# netbeans 7.3 - javascript autocomplete parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, netbeans, netbeans-7.3

Since upgrading to netbeans 7.3, I got into a problem where netbeans does not automatically provide me the parameter names.

For example,

In the autocomplete pop-up, I will see a  "methodA(param1,param2) xxx.js".  But once I click on it or press enter, it will only fill in methodA(). Ctrl+ P does not give me the parameter list either.

This is very annoying that I have to go find out the entire parameter list.  IS there any way to overcome this?

Comment: i just tested it my self! its like you said!
they just removed it! :( no plugin, no update... let's wait for next version or work with 7.2 again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230052) doc netbeans already fixed it, i think you should update to 7.3.1 from the main page, and it will work again.

Also, i suggest to report the bug to them, might help for further users.

GoodLuck!

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut to find the function is cntrl+space

Answer (score 0):

By default, autocomplete is disabled for javascript variables, go to preferences > Editor > code completion >  Javascript > and select all possible situations 
That was my issue at least :)